# Android street view showing black screen while loading

Tags: android, google-street-view, panoramas

I can able to load and see the Street view in my fragment but **while loading it is showing a black blank screen**. Is there any solution to avoid this blank screen while loading it.

Here is the code I placed in XML to show Panorama:

```
<com.mypackagename.CustomStreetViewPanoramaView
        android:id="@+id/streetViewPanorama"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addressLL" />
```

In Fragment on initUI calling `getStreetViewPanoramaAsync`:

```
override fun initUI() {
        streetViewPanorama?.postDelayed({
            streetViewPanorama?.onCreate(Bundle())
            streetViewPanorama?.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync {
                onPanoramaReady(it)
                presenter?.getNearByPanorama(50, 0.5f)
            }
        }, 500)
    }

private fun onPanoramaReady(streetViewPanorama: StreetViewPanorama?) {
        isPanoramaLoaded = true
        panorama = streetViewPanorama
    }
```

After getting location info from presenter setting panorama position like:

```
override fun setPanoramaPosition(locationInfo: LocationInfo, radius: Int, zoom: Float) {
        if (isPanoramaLoaded) {
            setState(progress = true)
            val location = LatLng(locationInfo.latitude, locationInfo.longitude)
            panorama?.setPosition(location, radius)
            panorama?.isStreetNamesEnabled = true

            panorama?.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener { streetViewPanoramaLocation ->
                run {
                    if (streetViewPanoramaLocation?.links != null) {
                        // if streetViewPanoramaLocation is present then set camera position
                        val panoramaLocation = panorama?.location?.position
                        val heading = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(panoramaLocation, location)

                        val camera = StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                                .zoom(panorama?.panoramaCamera?.zoom?.plus(zoom)!!)
                                .tilt(panorama?.panoramaCamera?.tilt!!)
                                .bearing(panorama?.panoramaCamera?.bearing!!)
                                .build()
                        panorama?.animateTo(camera, 100)
                        setState(progress = false)
                    } else {
                        // if streetViewPanoramaLocation not available in 50 meter radius then try with 100 radius
                        if (radius != 100)
                            presenter?.getNearByPanorama(100, 0.5f)
                        else // if not found within 100 meter radius show error message
                            setState(error = true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about setting `CustomStreetViewPanoramaView` to `visibility=gone` and adding a simple loading animation above it in your layout ? Once the `onPanoramaReady` function is triggered add some code that will hide the loading animation and set the visibility of your panorama element to `visible`

Comment: Good thought but I want to know why is that blank screen showing while loading it?

Comment: And if any error occurs or if no panorama found for that location then it is showing the black blank screen. In that case I am showing a error message with Retry button which is not visible as it is black screen.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure why is it showing a black blank screen, since I don't have a full code I can't test it truly. This was just a suggestion. But hope someone else can help you out more :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, for now, I am going with the same solution as you suggested.

Comment: I tried this way by setting `CustomStreetViewPanoramaView` to `visibility=gone` in initUI() and make it visible in `onPanoramaReady` then in-between while going to `setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener` still it is showing black blank screen again.

Comment: Finally worked when I made visibility as `INVISIBLE` instead of gone. ;)